# Kill processes from another user

Tags: vnc, process, kill, user-profile

I have set up Ubuntu server as a VM, and think I've installed vnc on it; However, I have been trying for a while.

When I couldn't connect using the vnc from any other machine, on both the same lan and through a natted router. I installed a vnc viewer on the same server to try and connect to 127.0.0.1.

That did not work, so now I can only log on as guest, so I want to kill the process that is running on the single main account I set up.
I have the password for my account but when I try and log on - it just goes back to the log on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seems frustrating. 
Fix your logon bug first.(should work on ubuntu 13.04)

1. Log on to the Guest account.
2. press Ctrl+Alt+T
3. Then write su fred(if this your user name)
4. Type in your password and press enter(no characters should appear while typing)
5. Then paste these command's and press enter

sudo rm ~/.Xauthority

sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg

sudo reboot

Try then to login to the account fred, and fix your vnc from there.

Comment: Thank you veqard, this is a nice clear answer. however, when I entered 'rm ~/.Xauthority' it came up with 'Permission denied'. So, i entered 'sudo su' then it asked me the fred's password, so I put that in and tried 'rm ~/.Xauthority' again, and this time it says 'no such file or directory'. Continued thanks...

Comment: try sudo rm ~/.Xauthority after you have logged in as fred (typing su fred)

Comment: Please carry on following the steps from my answer. Its been updated since my first post

Comment: Access to the vnc seems to be a networking issue, so I'll look into that. I've played with networks for longer that Linux, so that 'should' be easier :o)  Thanks again.

Comment: Bonus.............. The vnc is now working. I did nothing (other that messed around for the last 3 days!) but since your fix on the login, it seems to have had some effect on the vnc. So, a huge thank you :o))))